# Is it possible to introspect the array's type in Objective-C Generics -- Xcode 7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, introspection, objective-c-runtime

I use this to get the class for a property name:

```
- (Class)gm_classForPropertyName:(NSString *)propertyName {
    objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([self class], propertyName.UTF8String);
    const char * attr = property_getAttributes(prop);
    NSString *attributes = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:attr];
    NSArray *components = [attributes componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
    Class propertyClass;
    for (NSString *component in components) {
        Class class = NSClassFromString(component);
        if (class) {
            propertyClass = class;
            break;
        } else {
            class = swiftClassMapping[component];
            if (class) {
                propertyClass = class;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return propertyClass;
}
```

But this is the important part:

```
    objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([self class], propertyName.UTF8String);
    const char * attr = property_getAttributes(prop);
    NSString *attributes = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:attr];
```

When I log `attributes`, it still looks like an untyped NSArray as a string.  Is there some way to introspect the class type?

> T@"NSArray",&,N,V_children

### tl;dr

Take this class:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject <GenomeObject>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<SomeOtherClass *> *children;
@end
```

Given the class `SomeClass`, and the property name `children` is there a way for me to find that `children` is an array of `SomeOtherClass` type objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the WWDC talks about this feature, it is implemented using type erasure. That means that information about the generic is removed during compilation and not present at runtime.

This is the relevant video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=401. The `lightweight generics` discussion starts at about 22 minutes. At 27:20 they explain that it is implemented using type erasure.

Comment: Would love to, I'm trying to find which one it was.